# Scala generic: require method to use class's type

Tags: scala, generics

I'm pretty new to Scala. I'm trying to write an abstract class whose methods will be required to be implemented on a subclass. I want to use generics to enforce that the method takes a parameter of the current class.

```
abstract class MySuper{
  def doSomething:(MyInput[thisclass]=>MyResult)
}
class MySub extends MySuper{
  override def doSomething:(MyInput[MySub]=>MyResult)
}
```

I know that `thisclass` above is invalid, but I think it kind of expresses what I want to say. Basically I want to reference the implementing class. **What would be the valid way to go about this?**

Comment: You mean "this class" or "this object"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a neat little trick:

```
trait MySuper[A <: MySuper[A]]{
  def doSomething(that: A)
}

class Limited extends MySuper[Limited]{
  def doSomething(that: Limited)
}
```

There are other approaches but I find this one works fairly well at expressing what you'd like.